# Is it bad practice to have "parent" sitemap name inconsistent with "child" sitemaps?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap, filenames

My client is using the Fitpro Theme for WordPress which comes with predefined post types i.e fitness_class. However he wanted it changed to "classes" for the permalink and seo reasons. So I made the changes in the template files.

However the sitemap still picks up the original "example.com/fitness_class-sitemap.xml" (which I have called the parent), and if I select it I can see the correctly named (children) sitemaps for "example.com/classes/exampleClass".

Is there anything wrong with this? Do I have to actually recreate the post type in the template files? "Fitness-Class" has absolutely no relevance to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the entries in the sitemap point to the correct URLs and Google knows to access the sitemap file and is doing so, you're fine. The name of that file is not relevant to the SEO.

In other words, my sitemap could be `www.mysite.com/f*ckyougoogle.xml` and neither the spider nor the algorithm would care.